# how to point to the correct table row in a jQuery/Ajax function within php programme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am struggling to tell my jQuery function (which sits in a php programme) to identify the correct row in a dynamically generated table that shows a photo in every row of the table. I want to load the tags that belong to a photo, using the Ajax "load" method, into a div in a cell of **only** that particular row in the photos table that the user clicks on. The number of rows in this table is defined by a variable of which I do not know the value in advance. Each row in the table has the following divs:

```
echo "
$Photo_Counter = 0; // set $Photo_Counter to zero before  
    searching through photos in a database
<table>
    ...foreach loop // this loop brings up all the photos found 
          in a search through a database
    $Photo_Counter = $Photo_Counter + 1;
    ...
    <tr>
        <td>$Photo_Counter</td> // this shows the number of the row
        <td>
            <div class='see_raw_tags'> 
                <a href='flickr_photos_getInfo.php?Photo_ID=$photo_id'>see the tags</a>
            </div>                            
            <div class='raw_tags'> //this is the place that should receive the photo's tags
            </div>";
        </td>
        <td>$Photo</td> //this shows a photo
    </tr>
</table>
```

The `div class='see_raw_tags'` in every table row contains a unique hyperlink on which the user can click to see the tags of the photo in that row. This will trigger the jQuery function to load the tags into the empty "raw_tags" div area with the Ajax load method.

This is the jQuery/Ajax coding:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.see_raw_tags a').click(function(e)
    {        
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.raw_tags:nth_child('+photo_counter')').  
            html('loading...').load(url);
        var photo_counter = <?php echo $Photo_Counter; ?>;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

I have a row counter running in php (called:`$Photo_Counter`) during the generation of the table. I now want to insert the photo's tags only in the row on which the user clicked using the php variable `$Photo_Counter` by first converting it into a JavaScript variable called `photo_counter`. But it is not working. I just see the correct tags appearing in a new browser screen rather than in the appropriate cell and row in the table with photos.

Question: I am sure the problem sits in the jQuery coding. But what am I missing here? What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Is it a new window or the html of your current window is replaced with the tags because of html function?

Try. $(this).htm...  instead of html() ans start from there.

If i were you, i'd add the id of the row to the object containing the url, so while rendering the table youd add a href...  data-rownum="$photocounter"and in your js you do $(this).parent().load(...)

Comment: The existing window is replaced by a new window with the URL /flickr_photos_getInfo.php?Photo_ID=20688149511 if I click on the hyperlink for photo with ID 20688149511.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work because of your help by simply changing the jQuery/Ajax function into:     `$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.see_raw_tags a').click(function(e)
        {        
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $(this).html('loading...').load(url);
            e.preventDefault();
    });
});`